# Сортировка результатов mysql по двум столбцам

Tags: mysql, select, order

Имеется база данных типа:

```
field1         price
1 вариант      500
2 вариант      600
1 вариант      700
3 вариант      800
```

На сайте (каталог продукции) данные группируются по столбцу field1, а столбец price вытаскивается в виде `<select>` отдельным запросом mysql (без группировки)

Как сделать сортировку данных по цене и по столбцу field1, на подобии этого (только правильно) :

```
ORDER by `price` where `field1` = '1 вариант' ASC
```

Варианты с использованием `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = '1 вариант'`  не подходят, т.к. запрос генерируется автоматически кодом в зависимости от настроенных фильтров, и вытаскивает данные всех ячеек для дальнейшей работы.

Comment: а что в `ORDER by` уже `where` можно писать?

Comment: фраза "только правильно" Вам о чем нибудь говорит? Так мне было проще объяснить задачу.

Comment: если я правильно понимаю то должно быть так : SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE field = '1 вариант'
ORDER BY price, field ASC

Comment: Виноват забыл уточнить, что данный вариант не возможен, т.к. выборка в данном запросе генерируется автоматически в зависимости от фильтров, возможно только изменение ORDER by.

Comment: в order by  вы не сможете запихнуть where

Comment: я вкурсе, что не смогу использовать where в order by, однако предполагаю возможность использовать конструкцию типа  `ORDER by price + field1 ASC`

Comment: В order by в принципе любые операторы работают, так что и складывать можно. Но что вы хотите получить я из вопроса понять не могу. Приведите ваш запрос целиком и какой порядок вы хотите получить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl
ORDER BY
  IF(`field1` = '1 вариант', 0, 1),
  `price`
```

Разбейте результат на две группы при помощи вычисляемого выражения `IF(`field1`= '1 вариант', 0, 1)`, первой пойдет группа '1 вариант', потом все остальное. Сортировка по второму столбцу, приведет к тому, что внутри групп сортировка будет осуществляться по цене.

Comment: а возможно использовать 2 варианта с IF ?

Comment: Если вам необходимо выстроить больше вариантов, вам вероятно будет более удобен CASE, хотя и IF тоже можно использовать.

Comment: Дабы была понятна задача: в field1 указывается доступный размер торговой позиции, всего их  от 2 до 4 (назовем их вариант1, вариант2, вариант3, вариант4) и надо сделать сортировку по меньшему, т.е. либо это "1 вариант" либо это "2 вариант", т.к. один из них 100% присутствует, подскажите пожалуйста как, ибо не силен в ORDER by

Comment: @f1amestar а как задается меньшинство вариантов? По количеству записей в них или как-то иначе?

Comment: по названию, это магаз постельного белья, где то есть 1,5 спальное, где то 2 спальное, где то Евро, а где то Семейное, и где то данный размер есть, а где то его нет.

Comment: @f1amestar сортировка задается вручную? Т.е. всегда сначала 1,5, потом 2, потом Евро, потом Семейное или нужно как-то автоматически вычислять этот порядок? Если автоматически, то не понятно по какому критерию.

Comment: данные в mysql находятся по порядку, т.е. имеется ячейка ID, и выходит, что позиция с ID ниже всегда будет иметь меньший размер, в общем на сайте данные выводятся в виде массива и меньший размер показан таким образом: `$array[0]` - первый размер, `$array[1]` - второй и т.д.

Comment: В общем сам решил проблему благодаря MIN(), но все равно спасибо Вам.